# The center of the circumcircle lies on a side of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

Consider a triangle $ABC$. Let the angle bisector of angle $A$ be $AP,P\in BC$. $BP=16,CP=20$ and the center of the circumcircle of $\triangle ABP$ lies on the segment $AC$. Find $AB$.

> $$AB=\dfrac{144\sqrt5}{5}$$

[image]

By Triangle-Angle-Bisector Theorem $$\dfrac{BP}{PC}=\dfrac{AB}{AC}=\dfrac{16}{20}=\dfrac{4}{5}\\ \Rightarrow AB=4x, AC=5x.$$ The cosine rule on $ABC$ gives $$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2\cdot AB\cdot AC\cdot\cos\alpha \\ \iff 1296=41x^2-40x^2\cos\alpha,$$ where $\measuredangle A=\alpha.$ Is any of this helpful for the solution? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $O P$ is parallel to $A B$, hence by the intercept theorem, if the circle has radius $r$, we have $AB/r = (16+20)/20 = 1.8$

Comment: @Gribouillis, thank you for the response. Why $OP$ is parallel to $AB$?

Comment: I see it with complex numbers by choosing a basis where $AB$ is horizontal. If $B= r e^{i\theta}$ and $A = -r e^{-i\theta}$ then $P = A + 2 r \cos(\theta/2) e^{-i\theta/2} = r \in {\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis,  I haven't studied complex numbers, but we have $\measuredangle BAP=\measuredangle OAP=\measuredangle OPA=\dfrac12 \alpha$. So we can conclude $OP\parallel AB$, right? How can I find the radius $r$ of the circle?

Comment: Yes you are correct. It is now obvious.

Comment: @Gribouillis, can you explain to me how can I find the radius $r$ of the circle? Thank you in advance! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Gribouillis, we now have $AB=\dfrac{9}{5}r$. I still don't see how I can find $r$.

Comment: @IDoktorova apply sine law

Comment: @MathLover, well we have $\dfrac{BP}{\sin\measuredangle BAP}=\dfrac{BP}{\sin\dfrac{\alpha}{2}}=2R...$

Comment: $\angle APB = 90^0-A$

Comment: @MathLover, can you clarify that for me?

Comment: @Gribouillis, how did you get that?

Comment: $BOP$ is an isoceles triangle with angle $2\beta$ at $O$. It seems that the angle $POC$ is $\beta$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe that $\angle OPA=\angle PAO=\frac\alpha2=\angle BAP\implies OP\parallel AB$. Thus $$\frac{CO}{OA}=\frac{CP}{PB}\iff \frac dR=\frac{20}{16}=\frac54$$ Also, Power of a point yields $$\begin{align*}\text{Pow}(C)_{(APB)}=\lvert d^2-R^2\rvert&=20\cdot 36\\\iff \left\lvert\left(\frac54R\right)^2-R^2\right\rvert&=720\\\iff \frac9{16}R^2&=720\\\iff R&= 16\sqrt{5}  \end{align*}$$ Use $OP\parallel AB$ again in order to infer

> $$AB=R\cdot \frac{36}{20}=16\sqrt5\cdot \frac95=\frac{144\sqrt5}{5}$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! What is $d$?

Comment: Its the distance between $C$ and $O$: $d=CO$

Comment: Thank you! I haven't studied power of a point, though. Is there a simpler way to infer the equality?

Comment: [Power of a point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) is a very simple (and extremely useful!) tool; you should definitively have a look at it ;). But basically, the idea behind it is the following: Let $Q$ be the second interception of $\triangle ABP$'s circumcircle and $AC$. Next, prove that $\triangle CQP$ and $\triangle CBA$ are similar (*hint:* $\angle CPQ=\angle BAC$). This yields $CP\cdot CB=CQ\cdot CA$. Finally, notice that $CQ\cdot CA=(d-R)(d+R)=d^2-R^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I appreciate it. I think I got the idea for the power of a point theorem. Here it gives that $CB\cdot CP=CA\cdot CQ.$ How do you get from here $d^2-r^2=20\cdot 36.$ Why are we using absolute value?

Comment: @IDoktorova Yes that is correct. Now note that $AC = AO+OC = R+d$. Similarly $CQ = OC - OQ = d - R, CB = 36, CP = 20$. So $d^2-R^2 = 20 \cdot 36$.

Comment: Exactly. I use the absolute value because, theoretically, $C$ could be inside the circle.

Answer (score 3):

$\angle POC = \angle A$, so $\triangle COP \sim \triangle CAB$

Hence $\frac{R}{AB} = \frac{20}{36} = \frac{5}{9}$ ...(i)

$\angle APB = \frac{1}{2} \angle AOB = 90^0 - \angle A$

$AB = 2R \sin \angle APB = 2R \cos A$

So from (i), $\frac{R}{2R \cos A} = \frac{5}{9}$

$\cos A = \frac{9}{10} = 1 - 2 \sin^2{\frac{A}{2}} \implies \sin \frac{A}{2} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt5} $

$16 = 2R \sin \frac{A}{2} \implies R = 16\sqrt5 $

$AB = 2R \cos A = 32\sqrt5 \times \frac{9}{10} = \frac{144}{\sqrt5}$

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution using neither trigonometry nor power of a point:

[image]

You already figured out that $OP \parallel AB$, so draw two perpendicular lines $OQ$ and $BR$.

Let the radii $OA = OB = OP = 10x$.

Since $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle OPC$, we have $AB = \frac{20+16}{20} \cdot OP = 18x$, so $AQ = BQ = 9x$.

Therefore, $OQ = \sqrt{OA^2 - AQ^2} = \sqrt{19} x$, so $BR = \sqrt{19} x$.

$RP = OP - OR = 10x - 9x = x$.

$BP = \sqrt{BR^2 + RP^2} = 2 \sqrt{5} x$.

Given that $BP = 16$, we conclude that $x = \frac{16}{2\sqrt{5}} = \frac85 \sqrt{5}$.

Finally, $AB = 18 \cdot \frac85 \sqrt{5} = \frac{144}{5} \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Very easy to follow.